# How to run a Linear Regression on a plot obtained from a data dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, plot

I have loaded 3 .csv files into pandas dataframe and then moved certain attributes to a data dictionary and generated a plot of it. Can someone help me to run a Linear Regression for the data in the plot?

```
dept_delay_by_airport = small_flights_df.groupby(['ORIGIN_AIRPORT'])['DEPARTURE_DELAY'].mean()
dept_by_airport = small_flights_df.groupby(['ORIGIN_AIRPORT'])['DEPARTURE_DELAY'].count()
keys = dept_by_airport.keys()
data_dict = {k:{} for k in keys}
for key in keys:
data_dict[key]['delay_mean'] = dept_delay_by_airport[key]
data_dict[key]['departures'] = dept_by_airport[key]
x = [data_dict[k]['departures'] for k in data_dict]
y = [data_dict[k]['delay_mean'] for k in data_dict]
plot(x,y,'.')
```

[The image shows the plot I have obtained and I would like to run a linear regression for this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H25S9.png)
Thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

The `regplot` in seaborn might be what you're looking for:

```
import seaborn as sns

#some processing

sns.regplot(x, y, fit_reg=True)
```

Hope it helps.